# Python: Read huge txt file into csv row wise not working

Tags: python, csv, row

My code runs and properly selects the files in the folders. The problem is that it seems to not write the header on one line (which is all integers from 0 to 81923), as well as the text files themselves. Here is the code:

```
import os
import csv
import itertools

#path where the Neuroventure Participant data is stored

rpath = 'C:\Neuroventure\PreprocessedData'

#participant ID number
part_nb = 1

#adding header as integer values

with open ('C:\Users\SPISEA00\Documents\CSV files\NV_CT.csv', 'wb') as outcsv:
wr = csv.writer(outcsv)
wr.writerow([x for x in range(81924)])

#find files and write to csv    
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(rpath):
for f in files:
      if "V1" in f and str(part_nb) in f and "native_rms_rsl_tlink" in f and "30mm" in f and "asym" not in f and "left" not in f and "right" not in f:
            fullpath = os.path.join(dirpath, f)
            print f
            with open(fullpath, 'r') as in_file:
                stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
                lines = (line for line in stripped if line)
                grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 81924)
                with open('C:\Users\SPISEA00\Documents\CSVfiles\NV_CT.csv', 'a') as out_file:
                    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
                    writer.writerows(grouped)
                    part_nb = part_nb + 1

                    if part_nb == 121:
                        part_nb = part_nb + 1

                    if part_nb == 124:
                        part_nb = part_nb + 1

                    if part_nb == 127:
                        part_nb = part_nb + 1

                    if part_nb == 128:
                        part_nb = part_nb + 1
```

I think there might be some complications because of the text file format but I can't be sure. Any idea why it won't simply write all on one row? Here is a sample of one of the text files:

```
3.758533.070973.394973.124063.320233.301132.749053.422063.334462.626923.048533.717
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question as of now is essentially "please debug my code for me". Such kind of questions rarely useful for broader community and usually either barely answerable, or extremely simple (tpoy, syntax error, etc.) Please elaborate your problem further to have a more or less minimal reproducible sample, and ask specific, answerable questions. Refer to [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidance in creating good questions. For now, voting to put this question on hold.

Comment: Some suggestions...
1)  A few lines of the input file instead of just one
2)  Your expected output
3)  Early in your code, create a list `nums = [121, 124, 127, 128]`.  Then, consolidate your `if` statements into:
`if part_nb in nums:
    part_nb = part_nb + 1`
But, as it is, I'm having a really hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this - `grouped = itertools.izip(*[lines] * 81924)` , what kind of grouping is it?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. The goal is to create a csv file with each row representing the participant data. There are 81924 data points (floats) which have to remain all on one row. The gouping is done in order to write on one row. Without this part of the code it simply writes as columns (as far as I know). The input file is as I have stated. it goes on like this for the entire file, for 81924 data points.

Comment: The problem was with opening the file in Excel. It apparently has a column limit of 16 000, which is why it was messing up the formatting. Thanks everyone.